# Can Silicon Secured Memory prevent buffer overruns?

Tags: hardware, buffer-overflow, sparc

Oracle have [recently announced](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/pressrelease/sparc-m7-102615.html) the new SPARC M7 chip. It has an interesting feature called Silicon Secured Memory which claims to prevent memory corruption bugs like Heartbleed and Venom.

The idea is to add a "colour" to each pointer and 64-byte chunk of memory. On each memory access the colour is checked, and if they don't match, the program is aborted. There is [a picture](http://chucksblog.typepad.com/.a/6a00d83451be8f69e201b7c7e1b561970b-popup) and some [more detailed](https://blogs.oracle.com/raj/entry/the_holy_grail_real_time) information online.

The idea sounds promising. However, earlier attempts to solve buffer overruns (e.g. DEP) turned out to be less effective than hoped. Can SSM reliably prevent buffer overruns? What are potential attacks against the feature?

Answer (score 6):

> Can SSM reliably prevent buffer overruns?

It does not claim to offer 100% prevention but it definitely offers more granular protection compared to previous hardware based solution (which had usually page granularity) and much better performance than software based protections with a similar granularity. There are some limitations like

- Your code has to actually make use of it. This can be as simple as using the provided malloc, but custom memory allocations like done in OpenSSL need to be changed. And I don't know if the compiler will add such protection to the stack too or if this is only possible for data allocated on the heap.
- The memory must be aligned to 64 byte. Thus it will not detect when you overflow an allocation of 32 byte only.
- There are only 16 colors (4 bit) available for each 64 byte region. Thus the chance that some random pointer has the same color as the protected memory region is still 6%.

Thus it is not perfect but the chance to catch problems early and thus prevent attacks are much higher than with existing solutions, at least with solutions in the same performance class.

> earlier attempts to solve buffer overruns (e.g. DEP)

In my opinion DEP does not protect against buffer overruns at all but only makes sure that one can't simply execute code which was written to the stack or heap. Thus it only deals with some of the possible ways to make use of a successful buffer overflow, whereas SSM can help to prevent the overflow itself.

Answer (score 1):

As a supplement to the points the other answer here has already made I'll point out two additional concerns, noted in [this item from *The Register*](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/10/28/oracle_sparc_m7/):

**First:**
Even if an attacker's code incorrectly guesses the "color" that it needs to use in its malicious pointer (and that 1-in-16 chance of getting it right isn't quite trivial, at least in this context) and the exception from the processor causes the application in question to crash that's probably not going to be good enough in many cases. The target will need security or log-monitoring software in place to (a) see that the crash has occurred & recognize the special cause of it and (b) at the least sound the alert to administrators about the attack.  (Of course, preferably a sophisticated host-based IDPS would be in place on the target's servers, able to both recognize the exploit code that triggered the exception and take automatic countermeasures against it being run again in further attacks. Preferably...)

If, on the other hand, the application crashes go unnoticed and the crashed instances just automatically re-instantiate enough times eventually the attacker's code will hit that 1-in-16 chance of matching the color of the 64-bit memory block it wants to load. Bypassing this line of defense. In other words,  if you're not paying attention to what your applications and servers are doing you still might very well get burnt. (Yeah, duh.)

**Second:**
If an attacker can figure out some way to discern what the color of the specific memory block that he/she wants to load is or will be, the attacker may (*may*) just be able to *simply set the pointer to that color*.  How vulnerable to attacks along these lines is the new protection likely to be?  Well, to start to answer that is probably going to require more technical specifics than seem to be out there so far about how all this is going to work.  (Plus an answerer who knows way, way, *way* more about SPARC than I do.)

Even with the above concerns/limitations being out there, though, it's a really-interesting hardware-grounded security measure that seems more ambitious than what silicon makers  other architectures (cough...Intel ... ARM...cough) are trying to do to improve memory protection right now. (Even if the general concept of having protection keys/check-info for memory blocks is hardly new.)  It really will be pretty interesting to see how much of a real, positive difference in exploit protection (if any) this makes for Oracle shops.

Comment: And, to formally, directly answer the question "Can Silicon Secured Memory prevent buffer overruns?":  Well... we'll see.  :)